# Why doesn't a residual plot indicate whether or not the linearity assumption is violated?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, assumptions, linearity

I learned in stats that a residual plot is a plot of the residuals on the vertical axis and the independent variable on the horizontal axis. So basically it looks like the regression line turned horizontal if we are talking in two dimensions.

Now I also learned that if I observe a funnel shape in my residual plot, then that’s an indicator of unequal variances of residuals which I get.

But I was also told  that a funnel shape residual plot does not indicate that the linearity assumption is violated. **Why** is this the case?

If my residuals get larger as the independent variable gets larger, then that would seem to me that by extension, the dependent variable does not exhibit a linear relationship with the independent variables.

Comment: The residuals, by definition, measure *deviations* from linearity.  If, as you posit, their *magnitudes* vary *but their directions remain random,* then perforce you are not assessing any information about linearity.